How quick is the effect on intention in the theory of planned behavior?
I am currently doing a study where I try to model the theory of planned behavior via structural equation modeling. I have longitudinal data (4 waves) with items assessing behavior so I want to include a cross-lagged effect from intention in one wave on behavior in the following wave. My problem is that I don't know if I should model the effects of attitude, subjective norm, and perceived behavioral control (predictors) on intention within the same wave or if these predictors should have an effect on intention in the following wave. I'm leaning towards the first option since it makes sense to me that the effects of the predictors on intention would be immediate (e.g. if I already have a positive attitude towards a behavior it wouldn't take until the next wave to have the intention to do it). Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information on whether the effects of the predictors on intention are immediate or not. The original papers by Ajzen didn't give me a concrete answers and almost all of the longitudinal studies I looked at model the predictors and intention within the same wave without explicitly justifying an immediate effect.
Does anyone have an idea how an immediate effect could be justified or can anyone cite useful papers on this topic?
Any help is greatly appreciated!
